# Assigning array values to variable to avoid offset error

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 variables

```
$line1 = "";
$line2 = "";
```

And I have a `textarea` called `$textbox` that is separated by `\n`

```
$textarea_array = explode("\n", $textbox);
```

I want to assign `$textarea_array[0]` to `$line1` and `$textarea_array[1]` to `$line2`

However, if there is nothing in `$textbox` or if there is only something on the first line or second line, I get an offset error if I just do:

```
$line1 = $textarea_array[0];
$line1 = $textarea_array[1];
```

I have a lot of these "textbox's" and wasn't trying to do an extensive if, else, clause for every box so I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this instead of (which I think still doesn't work the way I want it to):

```
if(count($textarea_array) == 0)
{ 
    $line1 = "";
    $line2 = "";
}
elseif(count($textarea_array) == 1)
{
    $line1 = $textarea_array[0];
    $line2 = "";
}
elseif(count($textarea_array) == 2)
{
    $line1 = $textarea_array[0];
    $line2 = $textarea_array[1];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the indices first

```
$line1 = isset($textarea_array[0]) ? $textarea_array[0] : null;
$line2 = isset($textarea_array[1]) ? $textarea_array[1] : null;
```